# Teradata Active directory scan, Script show Job terminated with status 8

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I follow a blog post and run the script for active directory scan with TPT but No success.
No error show but just a message. ***Job terminated with status 8***

I follow this script to make a [test](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-parallel-transporter-active-and-batch-directory-scans).

I can't upload my codes here I see errors in my post just code and write more.

Any Advice please. Or suggestions?  I will be very thanks full.

Comment: This blog is quite old, have a look at the [TPT User Guide](https://docs.teradata.com/r/n~8eFynVbR1mVb2LM3ELaA/E1mHGqw8mV~oEzAXEwXeJg) for examples.

Comment: Status 8 is a syntax error in the script file. If there is no detail regarding that error, double-check that the -f option on the tbuild command line supplies the correct script file name.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by adding the table in TD.

Answer (score 0):

There was not any table to post the data in the Teradata database. I simply added a table in the database and it worked.